# Facebook Graph API Post's Photo Reactions Retrieval

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

## Background

From this change log: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/2020-02-03-endpoint-deprecations#photo, we can't get the reactions from each photos in a **page**'s post using {photo-id}. Our alternate solution at the time was using {page-id}_{photo-id} to get the reactions which works as expected, but now it returns the reactions of the original post instead, not from the individual photos which I'm not sure whether this is a bug or by design.

## Question

- Are there any other solutions for getting reactions from photos in a page's post?

## What We've Tried

- Read through the [Facebook Graph API reaction docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v16.0/object/reactions) (v16.0), which we've found nothing other than getting **likes** of a photo using {photo-id}.
- Tried using {page-id}_{photo-id} to get the reactions of a post's photo, but now it returns the reactions of the original post instead.
- Using {photo-id}/likes to get the number of likes of a photo in a post, but we prefer to get all reactions.